# Label a dataset according to bins of a histogram

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with over 40k rows. This dataset has 2 columns, `AccountNumber` and `NumberOfContacts`. I  created a histogram using the following code:

```
p <- ggplot() + aes(contactsInfo$NumberOfContacts) + geom_histogram(binwidth=10) + xlim(10,300)+
  xlab("Number of contacts") + ylab("Number of accounts")
p
```

I would now like to create an additional column called 'Bin' to my original dataframe according to the bins.

For example:

If an `AccountNumber` has within 0-10 contacts, then the column `Bin` should be equal to 1 for that `AccountNumber`.

Similarly, if an `AccountNumber` has between 50-60 contacts, then `Bin` should be equal to 5, and so on...

I can think of a ridiculous `ifelse` statement combination which will be extremely lengthy to achieve this task. I was hoping if there's an easier way to achieve this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: check out `mutate` in the `dplyr` package: http://www.r-bloggers.com/dplyr-example-1/

Comment: Remember you can do `gg <- ggplot_build(m + geom_histogram())` and explore `gg$data`, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know all the details of your dataset, but using `mutate` in the `dplyr` package:

```
mutate(contactsInfo, bin = floor(NumberOfContacts / 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
contactsInfo$binned <- cut(contactsInfo$NumberOfContacts, breaks = seq(0, 100, 10), labels = FALSE)
```